# How to declare a variable containing more than one integer values SQL Server

Tags: arrays, sql-server, variables

I want to store some id's in a variable then to use this variable multiple times wherever I have to use in queries. I used this format as:

```
DECLARE @aid INT
SELECT @aid = AP.aid
FROM 
    sub_aminer_paper AP
GROUP BY 
    AP.aid
HAVING 
    MIN(p_year) = 1990 AND MAX(AP.p_year) = 2014 AND COUNT(AP.pid) BETWEEN 10 AND 40

SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    sub_aminer_paper 
WHERE 
    aid = @aid
```

But this gives me the result only for any single ID from a list of ID's as I used query to retrieve multiple ID's from table `sub_aminer_paper`.

Please help and Thanks!

Comment: Create a temp table and store the results in it and then do the select. `INT` can not store more than one value.

Comment: Or a table variable or use this variable inside a while loop.

Comment: See http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a [table variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175010.aspx):

```
DECLARE @aid TABLE(id INT PRIMARY KEY)

INSERT INTO @aid
SELECT AP.aid
FROM sub_aminer_paper AP
GROUP BY AP.aid
HAVING 
    MIN(p_year) = 1990
    AND MAX(AP.p_year) = 2014
    AND COUNT(AP.pid) BETWEEN 10 AND 40

SELECT * 
FROM sub_aminer_paper 
WHERE 
    aid = (SELECT id FROM @aid)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this without using a variable, with something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sub_aminer_paper AP1
where exists (
  SELECT 1
  FROM sub_aminer_paper AP2
  WHERE AP1.aid = AP2.aid
  GROUP BY AP2.aid
  HAVING 
    MIN(AP2.p_year) = 1990
    AND MAX(AP2.p_year) = 2014
    AND COUNT(AP2.pid) BETWEEN 10 AND 40)
```

Comment: Or do the same thing using a CTE or derived table